# Group by, Sum, Join in Linq

Tags: linq

I have this simple sql query:

```
select c.LastName, Sum(b.Debit)- Sum(b.Credit) as OpenBalance from Balance as b
inner join Job as j on (b.Job = j.ID)
inner join Client as c on (j.Client = c.ID)
Group By c.LastName
```

and I am trying to convert it to work in linq like this:

```
from b in Balance
join j in Job on b.Job equals j.ID
join c in Client on j.Client equals c.ID
group b by new { c.LastName } into g
select new { 
     Name = c.Lastname, 
     OpenBalance = g.Sum(t1 => t1.Credit) 
       }
```

but when I try to run it in *LINQPad* I get the following message:

> The name 'c' does not exist in the
>   current context

and it highlights `c.Lastname` in `select new` statement.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've grouped `b` by `c.LastName`. So after the grouping operation, you're dealing with `g` which is a grouping with the *element* type being the type of `b`, and the *key* type being the type of `c.LastName`. It could well be that all you need is:

```
select new { 
    Name = g.Key,
    OpenBalance = g.Sum(t1 => t1.Credit) 
}
```

... but if you need to get at any *other* aspects of `c`, you'll need to change your grouping expression.